# Centos 7 kernel 6+ cannot recognize wifi-card

Tags: linux-kernel, iwlwifi

my Labtop is thinkpad nano，i7, installed centos 7, I update the kernel to adapt to touchpads and HDMI displays...

```
yum install -y kernel-lt --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel // 5.4.265-1.el7.elrepo
yum install -y kernel-ml --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel // 6.6.10-1.el7.elrepo
```

Launch kernel 5+, typeC-2-HDMI + Monitor doesn't work;
Launch kernel 6+, WI-FI not work;

```
lspci | grep -i net
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
```

Then I try to solve the wifi-card problem, display the messages when system starting

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmare found!
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77
```

while When I download the either one of 50～77 firmware form
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree, display the messages of "uCode file size does not match..."

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: uCode file size 9342899 does not match expected size
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmare found!
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77
```

the firmware for Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 from Intel Official Site https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html is Qu-*-48, not "QuZ-"

I tried different version for Qu- or QuZ, no luck, Could any help to solve this firmware dirver problem? I just want both of my wifi and HDMI-Monitor working, am I too greedy...

Comment: @telcoM thank you, problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When downloading firmware files from the linux-firmware Git repository through its web interface, use the `plain` link at the far right; otherwise you'll end up downloading a HTMLized hex dump of the firmware, instead of the actual firmware file.